ggplot: stat_contour_filled combined with ggpattern for region filling based on certain conditions
For example, I want to use ggpattern's stripes to fill in areas for values greater than 50. But the breaks parameter (probably my problem) doesn't achieve the result I want.
library(tidyverse)

d <- expand.grid(x = 1:10 ,y=1:10)
d$value <- 1:100

# The target area is concentrated in the upper right corner
ggplot(data = d,aes(x = x,y = y,fill = value))+
  geom_tile()

ggplot(d)+
  stat_contour_filled(aes(x = x, y = y, z = value),
                      breaks = c(-Inf, 50, Inf),
                      geom = ggpattern::GeomPolygonPattern, 
                      pattern_angle = 60,
                      fill = 'transparent', color = NA,
                      pattern = 'stripe',
                      pattern_fill = 'black',
                      pattern_density = 0.001,
                      pattern_spacing = 0.03,
                      pattern_size = 0.3) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(NA,'stripe'))

or
ggplot(d)+
  stat_contour_filled(aes(x = x, y = y, z = value>50),
                      geom = ggpattern::GeomPolygonPattern, 
                      pattern_angle = 60,
                      fill = 'transparent', color = NA,
                      pattern = 'stripe',
                      pattern_fill = 'black',
                      pattern_density = 0.001,
                      pattern_spacing = 0.03,
                      pattern_size = 0.3)

result:


You want to map the pattern aesthetic to a variable so you need to move it inside the aes() function:
ggplot(d) +
    stat_contour_filled(
        aes(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            z = value,
            pattern = value > 50 # this is new
        ),
        breaks = c(-Inf, 50, Inf),
        geom = ggpattern::GeomPolygonPattern,
        pattern_angle = 60,
        # removed pattern = 'stripe' from here
        fill = "transparent", color = NA,
        pattern_fill = "black",
        pattern_density = 0.001,
        pattern_spacing = 0.03,
        pattern_size = 0.3
    ) +
    scale_pattern_manual(values = c(NA, "stripe")) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")


A note on ggpattern options
This runs fine for me but for the OP returned the error:
Error in check_numeric_scalar(width, "width") : 
  width must be a numeric scalar

This appears to be related to ggpattern options introduced in R 4.1 as I could reproduce it by setting options(ggpattern_use_R4.1_gradients = FALSE, ggpattern_use_R4.1_masks = FALSE).
The following options resolved the error:
options(
    ggpattern_use_R4.1_gradients = TRUE,
    ggpattern_use_R4.1_masks = TRUE,
    ggpattern_geometry_funcs = NULL,
    ggpattern_res = NULL,
    ggpattern_use_R4.1_clipping = NULL,
    ggpattern_use_R4.1_patterns = NULL
)


So perfect! But when I copy the code you provided and run it, I get an unexpected error: “Error in check_numeric_scalar(width, ‘width’) :
width must be a numeric scalar”.
Very confusing.

After checking, I have the same version:

packageVersion(“ggplot2”)
[1] '3.5.1'
packageVersion(“ggpattern”)
[1] '1.1.1'

Confusing ......

I also tried it on both Windows & Mac devices and I had the problem. Kind of puzzling.

I'm currently using 4.4.2 and I'm not sure if that's the reason. Let me try 4.4.0.

I still have problems with R switching to 4.4.0 in my environment. Now wondering if it's a ragg version issue.

packageVersion('ggplot2')
[1] ‘3.5.1’
packageVersion('ragg')
[1] ‘1.3.3’
packageVersion("ggpattern")
[1] ‘1.1.1’


33: stop(paste0(name, " must be a numeric scalar"))
32: check_numeric_scalar(width, "width")
31: get_dims(width, height, units, res)
30: ragg::agg_capture(height = height, width = width, res = res,
bg = "transparent")
29: gridpattern_mask_agg_capture(x$maskee, x$masker, x$res)
28: makeContent.alpha_mask(x)
27: makeContent(x)
26: drawGTree(x)
25: recordGraphics(drawGTree(x), list(x = x), getNamespace("grid"))
24: grid.draw.gTree(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)
23: grid.draw(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)
22: drawGTree(x)

21: recordGraphics(drawGTree(x), list(x = x), getNamespace("grid"))
20: grid.draw.gTree(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)
19: grid.draw(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)
18: drawGTree(x)

17: recordGraphics(drawGTree(x), list(x = x), getNamespace("grid"))
16: grid.draw.gTree(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)
15: grid.draw(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)
14: drawGTree(x)
13: recordGraphics(drawGTree(x), list(x = x), getNamespace("grid"))
12: grid.draw.gTree(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)
11: grid.draw(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)

10: drawGTree(x)
9: recordGraphics(drawGTree(x), list(x = x), getNamespace("grid"))
8: grid.draw.gTree(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)
7: grid.draw(x$children[[i]], recording = FALSE)
6: drawGTree(x)
5: recordGraphics(drawGTree(x), list(x = x), getNamespace("grid"))
4: grid.draw.gTree(gtable)
3: grid.draw(gtable)
2: print.ggplot(x)
1: (function (x, ...)
UseMethod("print"))(x)

It does seem to have something to do with ragg.

I think I'm using a different graphics device to you. Do you still get the error with a different device e.g. p <- ggplot(...) and then ggsave("tmp.pdf", p, device = "pdf")?

For example, if I save the tile image in the question, it is not reporting an error.

I checked my Rstudio settings: graphics Dvice and Antialiasing are both default. the problem is still present.

It might have something to do with RStudio's graphics device - I'm using VS Code (on Ubuntu so that might also be a factor). What if you try in an R terminal?

Unfortunately, the problem still exists. Windows and Mac have the same results.

When I modified this line of the code you provided (although the result was not what I wanted):geom = ggpattern::GeomPolygonPattern togeom = ggpattern::GeomAreaPattern
It ran successfully ......

Tried changing fill = “transparent” to fill = NA and I still have the problem. Hopeless. Thanks for spending so much time troubleshooting with me!

@Breeze I think I've found the problem. I managed to reproduce your error by setting options("ggpattern_use_R4.1_gradients" = FALSE) and options("ggpattern_use_R4.1_masks" = FALSE). If you set both to TRUE does it disappear?

!!! Great! This really solves the problem! Thank you very very very much! I can sleep soundly tonight! : )
